# IE doesn't allow Google to be linked inside a iframe

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-8

I think they are going too far with this. I have this iframe:

```
<iframe width='425' height='350' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' 
 marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='http://www.microsoft.com'></iframe>
```

and it works, but when I put this:

```
<iframe width='425' height='350' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' 
 marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='http://www.google.com'></iframe>
```

a message saying:

> this content cannot be displayed inside a iframe ... bla bla bla

appears inside the iframe element.

I am using IE8. What is going on? Thanks!

**UPDATE** The same happens with Mozilla Firefox. What is this? A war field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Google doesn't allow it. One of the HTTP response headers when you request google.com is:

```
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: O.K. I understand. Monopoly rules. That's how a company starts going down.

Comment: It has nothing to do with a monopoly, it's a safety concern.

Comment: Yes, safety. In fact I was trying to include maps.google.com inside a iframe. I understand that they want you to specially go to their website.

Comment: If you use the link they provide they will allow you to use an iframe.

Comment: I can use this link in an iframe and the http header won't be sent: https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=atomium&aq=&sll=50.867511,4.374619&sspn=0.046748,0.132093&ie=UTF8&hq=atomium&ll=50.894946,4.341413&spn=0.014076,0.032015&t=m&output=embed

Comment: @ali Google provides a maps API. You don't have to send your users to their site in order to show maps - just use the API.